# How to iterate over JavaScript object when value of a value can be object?

Tags: javascript, json, object

**Edited question**. Thanks to @WiktorZychla for waking my Monday brain about recursion. Following code is now working as it should.

If I have an object like this dummy here:

```
const dummy = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: {
        d: 3,
        e: {
            f: 4
        }
    },
    g: 5
};
```

I can iterate trough it with:

```
const xavier = (value, s) => {
  for (const key in value) {
    if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (typeof value[key] === 'object' && value[key] !== null) {
        xavier(value[key], s + '.' + key);
      } else {
        console.log(s + '.' + key + ' ' + value[key]);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

This now prints the following:

```
.a 1
.b 2
.c.d 3
.c.e.f 4
.g 5
```

Comment: Ever heard of recursion?

Comment: Use lodash.js. It has some sort of flatten function

Comment: @WiktorZychla I actually had completely blacked out about it. Sorry for taking your time!

Answer (score 0):

after hard work i make a function that loop on any object:
 this will definitly iterate on how much level you want
please just take a look on it

```js
arr = [];
obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: {
    d: 3,
    e: {
      f: 4
    }
  }
}
function iter(x){
for(i in x){
if(typeof(x[i])=="object"){
iter(x[i]);
}else{

arr.push(x[i]);

}}}
iter(obj);
document.write(arr.join(','));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: this one is very beneficiant just look at it